# Azure IoT Hub for pure MQTT Clients - credentials exchange

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I want to connect pure mqtt clients with an Azure IoT Hub. These clients do not have a X509 certificate.
Is it a good idea to generate the SAS tokens for the mqtt client in my cloud backend and present the user one-time the SAS token in order the user is able to copy the SAS token into the mqtt password for the mqtt connection? Or are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that a better or more secure way is still to involve Device provisioning service but with SAS attestation and individual enrollment.

> SAS tokens have a hashed signature that is created using the symmetric key. The signature is recreated by the Device Provisioning Service to verify whether a security token presented during attestation is authentic or not.

Here you can find the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/concepts-symmetric-key-attestation) with code samples. 
This way you do not require the user to take any actions as well. With the proper implementation it can be zero-touch provisioning and onboarding.

Comment: Thanks. My problem with this is that the client or Device needs to implement special logic